# Timers in .addEventListener doesnt work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, setinterval, addeventlistener

I'm trying to convert a small piece of jQuery to vanilla JS, and I cannot seem to get timers to work within an `.addEventListener`.

I'm not sure if they can even work like this.

I've uploaded my work to Plunkr the greyed out code in the JS is the Vanilla JS.

https://embed.plnkr.co/up5i33T4LfTmpXhy86wM/

Everything works apart from the delay, it skips the delay as if its not there.

Here is the jQuery version which works great:

```
//jQuery VERSION
$("span").click(function (e) {
    $(this).parent().fadeOut(500, function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

And here is my vanilla attempt:

```
//JavaScript Version - DOESNT WORK!!!
var spans = document.querySelectorAll("span");

for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
    spans[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
        this.parentElement.classList.add("fadeOut");
        setInterval(test(this), 2000);

    });
}

function test(event){
    console.log(event);
    event.parentElement.outerHTML = "";
};
```

The CSS for the Vanilla is:

```
/* STYLES FOR JS */
.fadeOut{
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.6s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.6s;
}
```

and the HTML being manipulated is very simple:

```
<div id="container">
       <h1>TO-DO LIST</h1>
       <input type="text">
       <ul>
           <li><span>X</span> Go to Potions Class</li>
           <li><span>X</span> Buy New Robes</li>
           <li><span>X</span> Visit Hagrid</li>
       </ul>

   </div>
```

Comment: Passing in test(this) will actually run the function immediately and pass its return value. Use an anonymous function instead and call test() from it. You'll need to store a reference of this outside the anonymous function and pass that to the test() function. Much like you're already doing in the jQuery version actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to thank both @powerbuoy, @tryzniak and @Kavian K.

I used all of your answers and conglomerated the following which works perfectly:

var spans = document.querySelectorAll("span");

```
for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
    spans[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
        var _this = this;
        _this.parentElement.classList.add("fadeOut");
        setTimeout(function () {
            _this.parentElement.outerHTML = "";
        }, 500);

    });
}
```

I used @tryzniak and converted it to ES5 using elements of @Kavian K. suggestion and switching the `setInterval` which was giving me issues to `setTimeout` which fixed the issues.

Thanks guys, works smoothly now!

G

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working solution, based on @powerbuoy's suggestion:

```
var spans = document.querySelectorAll("span");

for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
    spans[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
        this.parentElement.classList.add("fadeOut");
        setTimeout(() => this.parentElement.outerHTML = "", 9000);

    });
}
```

Comment: This one works but creates a "Uncaught DOMException:" error that keeps firing off.

Comment: Oh yeah! This should be `setTimeout`! Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code snippet:

```js
var spans = document.querySelectorAll("span");

for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
    spans[i].addEventListener( 'click', function () {
        var elem = this.parentElement;
        elem.classList.add( 'fadeOut' );
        setTimeout( function () { elem.parentElement.removeChild( elem ) }, 600)
    });
}
```

```css
.fadeOut {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.6s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.6s
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <h1>TO-DO LIST</h1>
    <input type="text">
    <ul>
        <li><span>X</span> Go to Potions Class</li>
        <li><span>X</span> Buy New Robes</li>
        <li><span>X</span> Visit Hagrid</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

But you do not need to use a timer for hiding `<li>` elemenys.Simply add `height: 0` to your CSS:

```js
var spans = document.querySelectorAll("span");

for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
  spans[i].addEventListener( 'click', function () {
    this.parentElement.classList.add( 'fadeOut' );
  });
}
```

```css
.fadeOut{
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.6s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <h1>TO-DO LIST</h1>
    <input type="text">
    <ul>
        <li><span>X</span> Go to Potions Class</li>
        <li><span>X</span> Buy New Robes</li>
        <li><span>X</span> Visit Hagrid</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: The first example was great and did the job, with deleting the <li> after fadeout! - Which is exactly what I was looking for!

The second example looks like it works but it is cosmetic and does not delete the <li> in the HTML just sets the height to 0, which also creates an issue where the <li> that moves up into the space of the one that was set to 0 is no longer clickable.

The first solution was great! Thank You!

Comment: I also noticed because the elem was created outside the adEventListener scope it was creating issues when deleting the <li> elements occasionally, as soon as I moved the elem into the adEventListener scope it seemed to sort the issue out!